# Error: Activity class {} does not exist (only on specific phone)

Tags: android, adb, android-manifest

I was developing on my real device Xiaomi Mi 4c, no problems. Then suddenly (I guess after a system update) I ran into this error, when I try to run:

```
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/be.sebsob.red
Installing be.sebsob.red
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/be.sebsob.red"
Aborted 


Launching application: be.sebsob.red/be.sebsob.red.FullscreenActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start  -n "be.sebsob.red/be.sebsob.red.FullscreenActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=be.sebsob.red/.FullscreenActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {be.sebsob.red/be.sebsob.red.FullscreenActivity} does not exist.
```

(This is a new android studio default fullscreen app, without any changes)

Things I **tried** but **did not solved the problem**:

- Cleaned/Rebuild the project
- Re-imported the project
- Deleted the Build directory
- Deleted the ~/.idea and ~/.gradle directories
- Deleted .iml files
- Changed activity naming in Manifest.xml from .FullscreenActivity to full path
- Restarted my phone / computer / Android Studio
- Restarted Android studio with *Invalidate Caches / Restart...*
- Restarted adb via **adb kill-server** and **adb start-server** commands
- Killed abd process via Task Manager and restarted
- Re-enabled developer options on my phone
- Revoke USB debugging authorizations on my phone

**BUT** When I run this application on my other device (Xiaomi Mi2S) it works fine.

**AND** When I copy the .apk manually on my phone (where it fails to run from Android Studio) it installs and runs fine.
So I guess it has to be a problem specific when running from Android Studio to my phone? Could It be a read/write access permission error?
Any idea's?

**AndroidManifest.xml** (default, did not change after Android Studio new project setup)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="be.sebsob.red">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle** (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "be.sebsob.red"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you deleted the app on the phone via adb, then install a fresh version?

Comment: it seems there is a bug with your adb. try to restart it via adb kill-server and adb start-server commands respectively. And Morrison's answer also must work.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have deleted the app on the phone without adb. But the new default simple project I made to test was never on my phone before...

Comment: @UğurB when i run **adb kill-server** it says: _* server not running *_ when I then run **adb start-server** it says: _* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * * daemon started successfully *_ but when I then run the project I still get the same initianal error

Comment: I tried deleting the app with abd **adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.DELETE -d package:be.sebsob.red** but then on my phone i get a message: "app not found in the list of installed apps"

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071271/activity-class-does-not-exist

Comment: The problem is with run configuration in android studio

Comment: @mubeen thank you, but my run configuration are like they state, [have a look](https://i.gyazo.com/171cf02d0a22cc60fb130bf1be2fbf57.png)

Comment: is instant run on in your studio settings. disable it

Comment: @peeyushpathak Instant run is not activated

Comment: make sure another adb process not running in the task manager. if running kill it. then try to start adb again.

Comment: @UğurB I also tried that, did not fixed my issue, I ended up re-installing an older ROM version (pff), and that fixed it, thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after a long research I found out it had something to do with the adb not working properly **on my phone**. I don't really know why... But for more information check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103016/5297218

For me personally re-installing another (older) ROM version was the only thing that fixed my issue.

Comment: I have the same problem...What version are you using now??
If you find an other solution, please plublish it :)

Comment: @RoberV sorry for the late answer, but I have now MIUI V7.2.4.0 stable on my Xiaomi Mi 4c, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything and nothing was working for me!! Was very disappointed!!
Running on Samsung S8 (Android V. 8.0.0 API 26).
Just one thing worked and was:

1. build the APK (Build -> Build APK)
2. drag and drop the .apk file inside the smartphone Download folder using normal Android File Transfer
3. press and install the .apk (it will ask to change the setting for install from an unknown source)
4. after install the app you will be able to Run your Debug from Android Studio.

I hope this can help somebody because took me a while to figure this out.
The very very weird thing was that on Asus and on Pixel2 all of this wasn't a problem. I've been deleted and reinstall the app multiple tipe, only on the Samsung S8 with Oreo it was a problem, so probably samsung store somewhere the package name and if deleted then u cannot reinstall (The delete way that I used was through the Apps Manager).